# Is there a way to find text with spaces before and after string in excel?

Tags: excel, search, find

I am trying to update some addresses and fix case sensitive errors for example "123 Nw Apple St" should be "123 NW Apple St" I would like to be able to find all "Ne","Nw","Se" and "Sw." and if possible replace them with the correct version. However, I have yet to figure out how to even find these.

I have tried a couple different methods using search and find. The problem I am running into is Nw is not always at the end of address.

A couple things I have tried;

```
=SEARCH(" "&"Nw"&" ",A2,1)
```

and

```
=SEARCH(" Nw ",A2,1)
```

I just need some identifier that Nw is found. If it could replace it with "NW"
that would be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to capitalize all two-character directions without changing a word like:

**kitchenware**

then consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function TidyUp(sin As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    arr = Split(sin, " ")
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If UCase(arr(i)) = "NE" Then arr(i) = "NE"
        If UCase(arr(i)) = "NW" Then arr(i) = "NW"
        If UCase(arr(i)) = "SE" Then arr(i) = "SE"
        If UCase(arr(i)) = "SW" Then arr(i) = "SW"
    Next i
    TidyUp = Join(arr, " ")
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: This is great. What if I only want to see the values if a correction has been made? Is just comparing the two with a helper column the best way?

Answer (score 2):

`SEARCH` will return the position of the substring within the string being searched and is case insensitive. This can be used with `REPLACE` to achieve what you want:

```
=REPLACE(A2,SEARCH(" NW ",A2 & " "),3," NW")
```

Answer (score 1):

If they are all addresses where each word should start with a capital letter except for the four abbreviations, you *MAY* be able to do this:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(A2&" ")," Nw ", " NW ")," Ne "," NE ")," Se "," SE ")," Se "," SW "))
```

Otherwise, if you wanted to change "nw" to "NW" as well as "Nw" to "NW", you would need four more nested substitutions.

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2&" "," Nw ", " NW ")," Ne "," NE ")," Se "," SE ")," Sw "," SW ")," nw "," NW ")," ne "," NE ")," se "," SE ")," sw "," SW "))
```

[See](https://wmfexcel.com/2016/07/16/case-insensitive-substitute/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SEARCH` which is case-insensitive, and nested `IFERROR`s, to replace the directional abbreviations.

For example:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(REPLACE(A1,SEARCH(" nw ",A1)+1,2,"NW"),
REPLACE(A1,SEARCH(" ne ",A1)+1,2,"NE")),
REPLACE(A1,SEARCH(" se ",A1)+1,2,"SE")),
REPLACE(A1,SEARCH(" sw ",A1)+1,2,"SW")),A1)
```

However, if there are other issues you need to detect and correct, a VBA solution might be preferable.